# How to provide certificates to mongod containers on different nodes in swarm cluster for internal authentication?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am experimenting with mongod in docker swarm. I deployed mongod services in the swarm with docker-compose file (v3). My swarm consists of three nodes

`node1`
`node2`
`node3`

When I deploy mongod services using `docker stack deploy --compose-file <my-docker-compose-file>`, mongod services get distributed among three nodes and then I configure these mongod instances as replica sets.

To enable internal authentication in the replica sets, I need to provide x.509 certificates that are generated for the mongod instances running inside the containers. I have generated all the relevant certificates which are located inside a directory in `node1`. Now I need to provide these certificates to the containers running inside the services. I am not able to figure out a way to add configuration to the `docker-compose` file that will mount the certificates from `node1` to the containers running on `node2` and `node3`.

**I have tried:**

`services:
    rs1a:
    ...
    volumes:
      - certs:/certs

volumes:
    certs:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
         device:/path/to/dir/containing/certs/on/node1`

It didn't work and raised an error `no such device`

*Please note that when I redeploy services with compose-file, they might get distributed to any random node and therefore I need to have certificates for all the mongod instances in a place that can be shared. I can not have mongod instance-specific certificates on a node. I don't know if it is a good approach to the problem. Please suggest any better approach if there is one.*

Comment: Maybe a [volume plugin](https://store.docker.com/search?category=volume&q=&type=plugin) for a shared volume that is ro for all your mongo containers, but rw for a container that generates the certificates? You could do the cert setup in a seperate `docker-compose-certs.yml` file.

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to understand how will a separate `docker-compose-certs.yml` help.

Comment: It's a way to deal with short running or ad hoc tasks outside of your normal services.  Cert management is something you only want to run infrequently and also the only component that needs `rw` access to the shared certs. A seperate compose file keeps the cert setup definition in the same project, but not involved in your normal day to day `up` etc.

Comment: What I understand from your comment is - I can have a separate `docker-compose-certs.yml` file that can be used to mount volumes containing certificates. As adding certificates will not be an everyday task, I can separate it in a `docker-compose-certs.yml` and use `up` on that whenever required. Was I able to get your point?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  The point for your question is more about using a volume plugin for a shared volume though.

Comment: Yes, I get that. Adding a volume plugin will have added yet another dependency so, for now, I have decided to manually create volumes on each host machine and mount that into the container.